# Spring file returning errors on adding classpath

Tags: java, xml, spring

I want to make my application connect even without internet connection.
I am using Spring and at application-context.xml file; i have definations like :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans =
 org/springframework/context/config/spring-context.xsd   
 http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd =    
 org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">
```

But on writing the classpath in the schemalocation, I am getting errors :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Factory::getBean - java.lang.RuntimeException: Factory::createApplicationContext - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 4 in XML document from file [C:\Users\SaMali\Desktop\DSC\Solutions\Workday\DTL-DMT Codebase\DTL 1.6.1.5 code to be used\DTL 1.6.1.5\.\properties\hoover-spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 251; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at aggressor.util.Factory.getBean(Factory.java:201)
    at aggressor.util.Factory.getBean(Factory.java:201)
    at aggressor.util.Factory.getBean(Factory.java:174)
    at aggressor.core.Server.main(Server.java:423)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Factory::createApplicationContext - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 4 in XML document from file [C:\Users\SaMali\Desktop\DSC\Solutions\Workday\DTL-DMT Codebase\DTL 1.6.1.5 code to be used\DTL 1.6.1.5\.\properties\hoover-spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 251; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at aggressor.util.Factory.createApplicationContext(Factory.java:140)
    at aggressor.util.Factory.getBean(Factory.java:190)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: can you post your complete xml file

Comment: it is a huge file to post. If I run my file with follwing :
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"> 
it works. Only on adding the = org expression to facilitate no internet necessary to run, the error pops up

Answer (score 0):

try setting the schemaLocation correctly.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans = http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util = http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd"
```

Comment: it is still giving error: Failed to read schema document '=', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
 at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error with Java 1.8, so I have installed jdk-7u80-windows-x64.exe and add set the below variables

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin
SET CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80
```

and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

As per the stack trace,

It is telling that the xml is having some issue while reading . Hence, SAXParsingException.

Can you change the `xsi:schemaLocation:http\://`

to

```
xsi:schemaLocation:http://
```

And apply those changes where ever required. This may solve your problem.